# How to initialise a variable in Struct just once in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, static

This is my struct:

```
struct BookingDetailViewModel {

    private let bookingDetail:BookingDetail

    init(bookingDetail:BookingDetail) {
       self.bookingDetail = bookingDetail
    }

    var pricingCharts:[PricingChartViewModel] {

       let chartArray = bookingDetail.priceCharts

       var pricingChartArray:[PricingChartViewModel] = Array()
        for chart in chartArray {
           let pricingChartViewModel = PricingChartViewModel(pricingChart: chart)
           pricingChartArray.append(pricingChartViewModel)
        }
        return pricingChartArray
    }
}
```

This is my viewModel and when I try to access the value of **bookingDetailViewModel.pricingCharts**,  the array inside is computed again and again when accessed from tableView datasource which doesn't make any sense to me because the pricingCharts will always remain the same.

Is there any possible way of computing this pricingCharts just once, so I can get a better performance?

Am I doing it correctly or should I follow some other pattern while setting the pricingCharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a custom getter for your `pricingCharts`, and it behaves as it should - it recalculates (i.e. *gets*) its value every time it is needed.

What you need/want is a `lazy var`. Simply change your `pricingCharts` to :

```
lazy var pricingCharts:[PricingChartViewModel] = {

   let chartArray = self.bookingDetail.priceCharts

   var pricingChartArray:[PricingChartViewModel] = Array()
    for chart in chartArray {
       let pricingChartViewModel = PricingChartViewModel(pricingChart: chart)
       pricingChartArray.append(pricingChartViewModel)
    }
    return pricingChartArray
}()
```

There were three changes made :

1. `lazy` keyword before `var`
2. `=` sign between type and block
3. `()` braces at the end of the block

As usually you can red more [in the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: Error: Instance member bookingDetail cannot be used on type BookingDetailViewModel

Comment: Have you tried using `self.bookingDetail.priceCharts`?

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted.